# Fest swing gui framework, strange output

Tags: java, swing, input, fest

I am testing my SWING Gui.
I do this by using the FEST framework.

I have following input:

```
window.textBox("txtDatabaseConnectionString").enterText("jdbc:oracle:thin:10.254.202.27:1521:db");
```

it actually starts to fill in the textbox with following values:

> jdbc.oracle.thin&a

And than the test crashes...

I get following exception output

> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid key code '46'     at
>   org.fest.swing.core.RobotEventGenerator.pressKey(RobotEventGenerator.java:116)
>     at org.fest.swing.core.BasicRobot.doPressKey(BasicRobot.java:633)   at
>   org.fest.swing.core.BasicRobot.keyPressAndRelease(BasicRobot.java:618)
>     at org.fest.swing.core.BasicRobot.type(BasicRobot.java:589)     at
>   org.fest.swing.core.BasicRobot.enterText(BasicRobot.java:572)     at
>   org.fest.swing.driver.JTextComponentDriver.enterText(JTextComponentDriver.java:126)
>     at
>   org.fest.swing.fixture.JTextComponentFixture.enterText(JTextComponentFixture.java:208)
>     at
>   gui.GuiTest.shouldCopyTextInLabelWhenClickingButton(GuiTest.java:44)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

FEST had lot of issues regarding keyboard layouts. If your locale are not `en_gb/en_us` you may get that kind of problems. The keyboard input depends on your keyboard layout which is different in many countries and operating system. I noticed that it also changes the `:` into `.` in your example. In sources [here](https://github.com/alexruiz/fest-swing-1.x/tree/master/fest-swing/src/main/java/org/fest/swing/keystroke) there are only gb/en/de mappings. To solve the problem you can add your own keyboard mappings, as explained in this article: http://alexruiz.developerblogs.com/?p=1102

FEST looks like abandoned project and I am not sure if those are latest sources.

Comment: or I change the insertText method to setText?